# Least starting fields to full resolve a $5 \times 5$ normal magic sqaure?

Tags: magic-square

The image contains $16$ starting values. The remaining cells can be calculated by arithmetic operations, keeping in mind that the line sum is $65$. Now is there an arrangement where I need less starting values to full resolve the grid. 
[image: magic]

Comment: x x x x o / x x x x o /  x x x x o /  x x x x o / o o o o o   This sqaure could be resolved if all x varialbes were defined. Now is there an arrangments were i need less than 16 starting values

Comment: I do not know the minimum number of entries necessary to have a unique solutions, but I am quite sure, that $16$ is not the minimum number.

Comment: I am wondering if the middle cell is allways defined as 13, in the same way that a 3 by 3 sqaure must contain 5 in the middle cell

Comment: No, the middle entry can be any number.

Comment: You can even arrange numbers in a large square, such that any $5x5$-square in it is a magic square. For this, you need so-called pan-magic squares (Look here : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PanmagicSquare.html)

Comment: + + + + x
+ + + + x 
+ + + + x
x + x + x
x x x x x    Seems to be the minimum.

Comment: I do not know, if the solution is unique in this case.

Comment: The least field hypothesis implies that least field for order n= n^2 - 2n+1. How would one prove this

Comment: Probably only with exhaustive search. It was quite difficult to solve a related problem : How many entries are necessary to construct a sudoku with a unique solution. The answer was $17$, and the method to get this was simply brute force.

Comment: A naive analysis: We have $12$ equations and $26$ variables, so we could expect some way to do it by defining $14$ starting values.

Comment: @Peter consider the rank of the matrix. But that should be a good start.

Comment: @manu is it really conjectured that the number of clues necessary to produce a $n\ x\ n$-square which can uniquely be filled up, is $(n-1)^2$ ?

Comment: this seems to be the case for n= 1 2 3

Comment: assuming i know the centre value howmany leastfield must there exist